# Image not showing in vue and vue bootstrap

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I want to get image from assets folder in vue and 
Im using vue bootstrap

Here is my code :

```
<b-card title="Title" img-src='@assets/profile.jpg' img-alt="Image" img-top>
  <b-card-text>
    This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.
    This content is a little bit longer.
  </b-card-text>
  <template v-slot:footer>
    <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
  </template>
</b-card>
```

[Here is my hirarcy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iH8YY.png)

But it not working. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use relative paths for the various `img` (`img-src` in this case) props in bootstrap-vue components, you need configure `vue-loader` as explained in the documentation [here](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/reference/images/#component-img-src-resolving).

This should fix the issue you're facing.

If you cannot set the transformAssetUrls for `vue-loader`, you can `require` as an alternative.

```html
<b-card :img-src="require('../static/picture.jpg')"></b-card>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if using the `@` alias will work, so you might need to write a direct path to the image instead.

Comment: Thanks, its work.  :img-src="require('@/assets/profile.jpg')" both with alias or not its working